# Laravel Improve Sql Query WithCount using CASE

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Hi i want to improve my Query for dashboard stats i use withCount but its slow so i try to to use CASE Sql
My Code :

```
public function getWilayasApi()
    {

        $ids = Stats::where('order_stats',5)->pluck('id_stats')->toArray();

        $dataWilayas  = Wilaya::select('wilaya.mat_wilaya', 'wilaya.nom_wilaya')
        ->with([ 'statsPerMonth' => function ($query)  { $query->select(DB::raw('
            SUM(CASE
                WHEN stats_colis.id_stats = 10 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS on_process
        '),
        DB::raw('
            SUM(CASE
                WHEN stats_colis.id_stats = 3 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS returned
        '),
        DB::raw('
            SUM(CASE
                WHEN stats_colis.id_stats = 4 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS delivered
        ')); } ])
        ->paginate(10);


        return response()->json($dataWilayas);
    }
```

the relation in my Model :

```
public function statsPerMonth()
    {

        return $this->hasManyThrough(StatsColis::class, Colis::class, 'wilaya_id', 'id_colis', 'mat_wilaya', 'id_colis')
        ->whereBetween(
            'stats_colis.updated_at',
            [Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()]);

    }
```

Please need help

Comment: Does this query works right now? you have to include relation columns in `statsPerMonth` relation for laravel to relation to models

Answer (score -1):

the solution  :

```
public function getWilayasApi()
    {
        $ids = Stats::where('order_stats', 5)->pluck('id_stats')->toArray(); 
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $startOfMonth = $now->copy()->startOfMonth();
        $endOfMonth = $now->copy()->endOfMonth();
        $dataWilayas = DB::table('wilaya')
        ->select('wilaya.mat_wilaya', 'wilaya.nom_wilaya')
        ->selectRaw('COUNT(CASE WHEN stats_colis.id_stats = 10 THEN stats_colis.id_colis END) as on_process')
        ->selectRaw('COUNT(CASE WHEN stats_colis.id_stats = 3 THEN stats_colis.id_colis END) as returned')
        ->selectRaw('COUNT(CASE WHEN stats_colis.id_stats = 4 THEN stats_colis.id_colis END) as delivered')
        ->leftJoin('colis', 'wilaya.mat_wilaya', '=', 'colis.wilaya_id')
        ->leftJoin('stats_colis', 'colis.id_colis', '=', 'stats_colis.id_colis')
        ->whereBetween('stats_colis.updated_at', [$startOfMonth, $endOfMonth])
        ->groupBy('wilaya.mat_wilaya', 'wilaya.nom_wilaya')
        ->paginate(10);

    return response()->json($dataWilayas);
}
```

Comment: You should take a minute to [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76507534/edit) and explain _why_ this is the solution. Answers (even to your own question) with no context are generally not helpful to others, especially those who are learning.